# What is the efficient way to compute ${n \choose r} \mod k$?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

We know that

$n\choose r $ = $\frac {n-r+1}{r}$$  n\choose r-1$

And we also know that

$(a * b) \mod k  = ((a\mod k) *(b\mod k)) \mod k$

Fermat's Little theorem

$a^{\phi(m)-1} = a^{-1} \mod m$

and

$n \choose 0 $=$1$

so we can compute

${n\choose r} \mod k $ = $(((n-r+1)\mod k)*(r^{\phi(k)-1}\mod k)*({n\choose r-1}\mod k))\mod k$  $ \forall \;r\; >= 1\: and \; r<=n$ <------ equation 1

If equation 1 hold for all n , k, r with constraint r<=n and n>=1 then

we can compute ${n\choose r}\mod k $ using    $n\choose r-1$

You can check that equation 1 doesn't hold for all n , r, and k why ?
can we compute in some other way efficiently ?
Assume n could be upto $10^10$ and k could be upto $10^20$ and greater than 1.

Comment: If $k$ is square free, you can easily compute it with Lucas Theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem

Comment: The case $k$ is a prime, we have Lucas theorem http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Lucas%27_Theorem, or $k$ is a power of a prime, we have Wolstenholmes theorem http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolstenholme%27s_theorem

Comment: @TienKhaPham Jef But why equation 1 is not valid ?

Comment: @john I wonder why there is "Modules" tag?

Comment: @math137 since we have to find mod k .

Comment: if k is a prime number we can compute it easily (n!%k)*mod-inverse(r!,k)*mod-inverse((n-r)!,k). For computing mod-inverse we can use ferment theorem or extended Euclid method, for factorial pre-compute it and store in hash-table.Is it not simple.